# How to remove redundant GitHub entry

Tags: git, github, team-explorer

As you can see below, due to a faulty attempt to create a GitHub repository, I now have one WallE entry in `GetHubVisualStudio\WallE` and another one in `GitHubVisualStudio\WallE\WallE`.

I've tried everything I can think of to get rid of this duplicate entry. I even deleted the entire folder and re-cloned it from GitHub and the redundant entry just came back. How do I get rid of this extra?

[image: Redundant GitHub entry]

**Update**: Browsing through Process Monitor, it looks like this might be a case of Visual Studio caching the repository locations and providing no way to clear incorrect entries. Since they've moved the repository entries from a standard registry entry to an application hive, it appears there's nothing to be done unless there are registry editors out there that can access application hives in some fashion.

Comment: Is the duplicate *in* your repository, or just on your filesystem?

Comment: Given that it went away when I deleted the folder, then came back when I recloned it, I'd say it's in the repository itself.

Comment: I think part of the problem is that WallE\WallE still exists, even though there's no .git folder in it. If I rename that folder, I can get rid of the entry, but as soon as I rename it back, the redundant entry also comes back.

Answer (score 0):

### Remove Files from Index and Tree

I don't know your GUI tool, but from the command line (assuming Cygwin or Git-Bash) you can remove a directory as follows:

```
cd C:/Users/rmorl/Documents/GitHubVisualStudio/WallE
git rm -rf WallE
git commit -m 'Remove duplicate directory tree.'
git push
```

### Purge Working Tree

If you still have problems, make sure you have a backup first. You might then look at incorporating commands like:

- `git ls-files   # list files that Git knows about`
- `git clean -fdx # purge working tree of files/dirs not in the Git index`

### Last Resorts

If all else fails, install a tool like [BFG](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to perform surgery on your repository, and then force-push the result back upstream.

Comment: I tried all that and it came back as soon as I restored the folder. (There's *supposed* to be a WallE\WallE, it just shouldn't show up as if it's a separate repository.)

Renaming the folder seems to be the only solution that gets rid of the extra repository entry. I didn't try BFG, as I don't really understand GIT all that well in the first place, and don't want to mess with something even more powerful/complex that might do odd things to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

My second theory, that it was a cached location in Visual Studio that was creating the issue, turned out to be correct. This solution is not for the faint of heart. :)

1. Close all Visual Studio instances.
2. Locate `privateregistry.bin`. For me, this was in `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_3c403b8b`.
3. Run regedit.exe.
4. Click on a key that allows loading custom hives, such as HKEY_USERS.
5. Click on File, Load Hive, and load `privateregistry.bin`. (If it won't open, you may need to get creative. I chose to make a copy of it and load that, then copy it back later, at which point, the file was no longer protected. Rebooting might also be an answer.)
6. Navigate to `Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_3c403b8b\TeamFoundation\GitSourceControl\Repositories`.
7. Remove any invalid entries you find there.
8. Unload the hive, then exit Regedit.
9. If you had to get creative in Step 5, copy the file back over the original.

The next time you open Visual Studio, the invalid entries will no longer be displayed.